# Showing that $x^5 - 5 a^4 x + a$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

A problem of finding a Galois group of $x^5 - 5 a^4 x + a$ appeared in a previous prelim at my school for $a \in \mathbb N$, and the only hard part seems like showing that the polynomial is irreducible, since it has 2 complex roots.

However, I do not know about any algebraic way to show that above is irreducible—other person from my school showed it by using rational root theorem and Rouche’s theorem.

So I was wondering if there is any way to show that above polynomial is irreducible in a purely algebraic way.

Comment: Irreducible over what? $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Is the rational root theorem not an algebraic method?

Comment: @Cameron Williams Yes

Comment: @aschepler It was used to conclude there is no linear factor, but Rouche’s theorem is not an algebraic method.

Comment: If $a$ has at least one prime factor that has an exponent of $1$, then the polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @Tob Ernack We also noticed that, but couldn’t generalize that to all natural $a$.

Comment: Newton polygons method covers all cases where $a$ is not a fifth power of an integer (for a prime $p\mid a$ such that $d:=v_p(a)$ is not a multiple of $5$, we have newton polygon to be the lower convex hull of points $(5,0),(4,v_p(5)+4d),(0,d)$, which can be seen to be the line segment between $(5,0)$ and $(0,d)$, and since it does not cross any other integer points (by $5\nmid d$), Dumas' criterion gives us irreducibility (you can see it uses a bit of geometry)

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. For $a\in \Bbb{Z}$

- If $a=0$ then it is reducible, if $a=\pm 1$ then it is irreducible $\bmod 3$.
- If $a$ is not a 5th power then $f(x)=x^5+5a^4x+a$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ whenever $5\nmid v_p(a)$, because $f(\gamma)=0$ gives that $v_5(\gamma)=v_5(a)/5$ so that $[\Bbb{Q}_p(\gamma):\Bbb{Q}_p]\ge 5$.
- Otherwise $a= b^5$. Let $g(x)=a^{-1} f(xb)=x^5+5b^{16}x+1$, $h(x)=g(x-1)=x^5 - 5x^4 + 10x^3 - 10x^2 + 5xb^{16} + 5x- 5b^{16}$

  If $5\nmid b$ then it is Eisenstein at $5$.
- It remains to check the case $a=(5c)^5$.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193201/showing-x5-ax-1-in-mathbbzx-is-irreducible to complete the proof. I assume the same method can be employed without using p-adics (since it is a qual problem); namely one can reduce to a degree $2$ and a degree $3$ factor and try to match coefficients.

Comment: Indeed I was trying to see why it didn't have a linear factor.

Comment: @reuns, your polynomial $g(x)=x^5+5b^{16}x+1$ clearly doesn't have a linear factor if $b\not=0$. (The rational root theorem says the only possible roots to check are $1$ and $-1$.)